# How to change the input into form format in Python?

Tags: python, format

I have data input like this:

```
day_i = [“Bob: 1200”, “Alice: 2500”, “Celia: 110”, etc…]
```

I want my output to look like a form and calculate the sum of number, like so:

```
Customer    Total purchase
Alice       100
Bob         120
Celia       110
```

Comment: Is day_i supposed to be a dictionary? If so, you should write
 ```day_i = {“Bob": 1200, “Alice": 2500, “Celia": 110, …}```

Comment: Don't use curly quotes in code.

Comment: @maomao-yi Which version of python? are you using `python2` or `python3`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `day_i` is meant to be a proper Python dictionary, this is what I think you're asking for.

```
day_i = {                                                                                                                                          
    'Bob': 1200, 
    'Alice': 2500, 
    'Celia': 110 
}

print("{:15s}{:15s}".format("Customer", "Total Purchase"))
for person in day_i:
    print("{:15s}{:<15d}".format(person, day_i[person]))
```

Before using this code, I suggest you read more about Python's string.Formatter class [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html).